# android database returning no records but sqlitebrowser contains data

Tags: android, sqlite, android-assets

I have a problem with a database file not being read 
I have added the database file in assets called mydb but when i run my code it says its not being located. It is calling this toast Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); This is being called because no records are being returned. Also I know it is finding the file as there is no FileNotFoundException exception. This is an example form Android Application Development book.

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    TextView quest, response1, response2;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView quest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quest);


        try {           
            String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/MyDB";
            File f = new File(destPath);            
            if (!f.exists()) {          
                CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"), 
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 


        //---get a contact---
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getContact(2);
        if (c.moveToFirst())        
            DisplayContact(c);
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "No contact found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();



    }

    public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
    throws IOException {
        //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }

    public void DisplayContact(Cursor c)
    {
    quest.setText(String.valueOf(c.getString(1)));      
        //quest.setText(String.valueOf("this is a text string"));    
    } 
}
```

Is there a better way to upload data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things come to mind here...

1. because of the `!f.exists()` check, then once the database exists (and maybe empty) then it will never copy it again.  So maybe for now, copy it all the time, until you work out kinks and then add in the `!f.exists()`
2. I've had mixed results with `e.printStackTrace()`, maybe change to `Log.e(TAG, "message", e)` and see if you start seeing errors showing up in LogCat

As for a better way... I've done this a couple different ways...
1. Is to create a file (json, cvs, etc) and then process and load it, if the database is empty
2. Similar to the first, except that I create a java serialized object array and load it to the database, if the database is empty.

Also I don't know what `DBAdapter` looks like, and since it wraps the database the issue may be there.

Comment: thanks I will give it a try. I dont think its the DBAdapter as I have used that for other examples and it works well. I have just had problems adding the db file to assets and for it to be read. It uploads fine. The data just doesnt seem to be read into the cursor so it can be outputted to an xml layout file.

Comment: But, is `DBAdapter` opening the exact same location as `String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/MyDB";`?  (same case in the filename as well, etc).  Perhaps, you are copying the resource database to a different file?

Comment: it was the name of the table i fixed it the table was called basic_table and this didnt seem to work. so i removed the undescore. I also took your advice about not using printStackTrace(). Also thank you for the advise for the !if.exists() statement